# To find relative importance of ordinal predictors for binary dependent variable

Tags: r, variables, statistics, regression, modeling

I am analyzing survey data that has dependent variable in the form of a binary variable (0 or 1) with 10 predictors and all are ordinal (scale 1 to 5, Strongly disagree-1, Disagree-2, Neither agree nor disagree-3, Agree-4, Strongly agree-5).

My objective is to find relative importance of these predictors in driving the binary dependent variable. I am using R to achieve this.

I have tried using ‘relaimpo’ package provided by R. Using the function

```
    model1_raw <- calc.relimp(data, type ="genizi")
```

Where I have converted my Dependent variable using

```
    as.factor (data$dependent)
```

and have used ordered factors for my independent variables using

```
    ordered(data$predictor1, levels=1:5)
```

But I am getting the following error massage (I do not have any NA value in my dataframe)

```
    Error in cov.wt(y, wt = wt) : 'x' must contain finite values only
```

Along with following warning massages

```
Warning messages:
        1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
        using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
        2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

My question is, Is it possible to get the results using the library ‘relaimpo’. If not what other methods, I can use to get the ‘relative importance of the predictors’

Comment: I am not sure what type of model you are using, but I suggest you look into discriminant analysis and take a look at this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900932/linear-discriminant-analysis-variable-importance

Comment: While using library relaimpo one can pass the dataframe with first column as dependent varable. the object in the argument in the function 

calc.relimp(object, type = "lmg", groups = NULL, groupnames=NULL, always = NULL, ...) 
which I have used.

Comment: `relaimpo` seems to have some trouble with factor variables as predictors. Take a look at this response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75137341/calc-relimp-delivers-an-error-about-finite-values-when-using-a-linear-model/76879246#76879246 for an idea of a workaround